# Bitbucket 2FA error when not enabled

Tags: git, bitbucket

I do not have 2FA enabled on my Bitbucket account, still when I try to access any of my repos I get the error `remote: Two-step verification is enabled for this account`

I even created a brand new account where I did not turned two step verification on. Still I get the same error, why and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials): it could have cached 2FA-based credentials.

```
git config credential.helper
```

If it has stored those credentials for `bitbucket.org`, that would explain why a new account is still affected by that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was set to manager, and username and pwd was stored in windows credential manager, after deleting, it worked.